# rails 3 nested/namespaced routes generate show action instead of new

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a rails 3.2.2 app with "patients" who can have several types of "appointments". So I made the following routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :patients do
  namespace :appointments do
    resources :default, :except => [:index]                                           
    resources :pilates, :except => [:index]
  end
end
```

relevant `rake routes` output:

```
patient_appointments_default_index POST   /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default(.:format)          appointments/default#create
  new_patient_appointments_default GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default/new(.:format)      appointments/default#new
 edit_patient_appointments_default GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default/:id/edit(.:format) appointments/default#edit
      patient_appointments_default GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default/:id(.:format)      appointments/default#show
                                   PUT    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default/:id(.:format)      appointments/default#update
                                   DELETE /patients/:patient_id/appointments/default/:id(.:format)      appointments/default#destroy
patient_appointments_pilates_index POST   /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates(.:format)          appointments/pilates#create
  new_patient_appointments_pilates GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates/new(.:format)      appointments/pilates#new
 edit_patient_appointments_pilates GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates/:id/edit(.:format) appointments/pilates#edit
      patient_appointments_pilates GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates/:id(.:format)      appointments/pilates#show
                                   PUT    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates/:id(.:format)      appointments/pilates#update
                                   DELETE /patients/:patient_id/appointments/pilates/:id(.:format)      appointments/pilates#destroy
```

Notice that I had to add make "default" and "pilates" uncountable on the rails inflector; otherwise I got some routes named "defaults" and others named "pilate":

```
#config/initialize/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( default pilates )
end
```

My problem is that any "new" action links I make resolve in a "show" action. For example, this:

```
link_to "Add", new_patient_appointments_default_path(@patient)
```

Produces this (valid, IMHO) url:

```
/patients/14/appointments/default/new
```

But when I click on it I get this error:

```
Started GET "/patients/14/appointments/default/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-18 11:29:31 +0200
Processing by Appointments::DefaultController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"patient_id"=>"14"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Patient Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "14"]]
  ...
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 512ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {
  :action => "show",
  :controller => "appointments/default",
  :patient_id => #<Patient id: 14, ...>,
  :id => #<Appointments::Default id: nil, ...>})
```

I have checked the obvious things; the @patient object is not nil, there are no "mass-assignment issues", and it's not a permissions problem. The controller is not receiving a "new" action and then detecting an error and redirecting to "show" or something of that sort.

It really seems that the url is badly parsed.

I've already invested several hours on this. If anyone has any pointers on how to fix it, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What's in your `DefaultController#new` action? Rails is clearly mapping the URL to your `new` action, which is loading a user and a patient. But somewhere after that it blows up.

Comment: @RobDavis thanks for your comment. I think I just found it. See my answer below.

Comment: Could be a bad path in your controller or view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies.

I tried rendering a trivial "text only" view for the "new" action, and it worked. So now I think it's an error in the "new" view. I still don't know why Rails was trying to render the "show" view instead of telling me about the error. But I think I can work from here. Will close this answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: No, I have to let 2 days pass before accepting my own answer.